# 삽십 v 삼십 - mistake or genuine alternative?

Tags: spelling

I bought a book of short stories in intermediate Korean and spotted 삽십 where 삼십 is clearly meant (the duration of a taxi ride). My Korea-born and -speaking wife confirmed this. Is that a typo (ㅂ (q) is above ㅁ (a) on the Korean keyboard layout I use) or a genuine alternative? There are about 12,000 Google results for 삽십, mostly from informal sources like social media. My wife hadn't encountered 삽십 before.

Comment: Its probably just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better if you provided the context where the word was used.
It seems, however, obvious that it meant 삼십 (30).
I have never heard or seen the word '삽십.'

Comment: The context doesn't add much. The book is 'Short stories in Korean - Intermediate' by Ollie Richards translated Yeouseon Gang and Hyojin An, in a series titled Teach Yourself (a commercially published book and series, produced in part by Koreans). The narrator and his sister are English university students travelling to Korea to study. They take a taxi from the airport to their friend's apartment. "삽십 분 후 서울 시내에 도착했어요".

Comment: @Sydney It is definitely a typo.

Comment: @Sydney Yes, in that context, it's absolutely a typo. Please consider accepting an answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: I have spotted typos in several textbooks, as well.